# 'Automatic Updates' and Public Versioning for .NET (desktop) application?

Tags: c#, versioning, upgrade

We're building a desktop based .Net application in C# which we want to include automatic upgrades with local desktop's polling our web server from time to time looking for updates.

What the best solution for public versioning management and also for including automatic upgrades in our Desktop .Net application?

Basically so the client installs our desktop software, say at version 15.1 and when 15.2 comes out their software is automatically updated to the latest version.

Comment: Thanks for the references to ClickOnce and .NET Application Updater Component. @KHoff your link included a reference to versioning: "..then specify the publish version (Major, Minor, Build, Revision), which specifies the lowest version number of the application that can be installed."  Anyone have a link to how I can implement versioning in my app which is in line with what the automatic update code is expecting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**.NET Application Updater Component** makes it really easy to add an updater to any application. It can be easily coupled with an existing project as well. The same method of using the UAB (Updater Application Block) is used by Microsoft in ClickOnce as well.

[Reference](http://windowsclient.net/articles/appupdater.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to suggest you to use [ClickOnce Deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/142dbbz4%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

In previous applications we have used [ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) which could be an option.
[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s22azw1e%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) is explained how updates are working with it.

Comment: Thanks for adding that link which explains how the updates work. The link mentions how it checks which version to use: ".. then specify the publish version (Major, Minor, Build, Revision), which specifies the lowest version number of the application that can be installed."